# syntax error in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i  `wana` create a `bst` tree in c++ but i have a syntax error in this code :

```
#pragma once
#include "BSTNode.h"
using namespace std;

class BST
{
private:
    BSTNode* root;
public:
    BST(void);
    bool insert(int );
    int search(int);
    ~BST(void);
};
```

and `BSTNode` is:

```
#pragma once
#include "BST.h"

class BST;

class BSTNode
{
    friend  class BST;
private:
    int data;
    BSTNode * LeftChild, *RightChild;
public:
    BSTNode(void);
    int getData();
    ~BSTNode(void);
};
```

my error is:

```
Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
```

i think  `dont` have error .please help me!

Comment: And the line of the error is?

Comment: line 8, near the BSTNode* root;

Comment: @Jesse that's not it. Giel has posted the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a circular include, with 2 files, and because of the #Pragma once, both files are only included once, and therefore BSTNode is parsed first and includes BST, but then BST is not including BSTNode anymore (because it is pragma once).

this leads to BST not knowing what a BSTNode is, solution would be:

Removing the include and forward declaring the class like such:

```
#pragma once
using namespace std;

class BSTNode;  //Forward declare class so that BST knows BSTNode (move include to .cpp file)

class BST
{
private:
    BSTNode* root;
public:
    BST(void);
    bool insert(int );
    int search(int);
    ~BST(void);
};
```

Example of main function:

```
int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
    printf( "\nHello World\n\n" );
}
```

Comment: I got the job done but a have new error : error LNK1561: entry point must be defined

Comment: You are missing your main function, normally declared in a file which resembles your projectname, could be any though, ive added the function signature to the answer at the bottom, this is where the program starts running, you could initialize your tree there for example

Answer (score 0):

declaration of ‘BSTNode’ with no type. You need to declare the class before using it